# Alasql - Manifest V3 migration error - doesn't allow content scripts to use eval() and friends

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, alasql

I'm having trouble executing eval() and friends for alasql, it is not supported to manifest v3 migration for chrome extension.
Based from their [Manifest V3 migration checklist](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/):

> You can no longer execute external logic using chrome.scripting.executeScript({code: '...'}), eval(), and new Function().

And got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Alasql is using the 'new Function()' class/method thingy, and it causes error in manifest v3.

Does anyone have encountered the same issue?

Comment: You will have to run this code inside the [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: I did have the same issue with a node_module in my extension. I think it's due to this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code. The second bullet point under the remotely hosted code header states that a code string passed into eval at runtime is not allowed. Not sure about the `new Function` issue